# WPF - при повороте куб плохо отображается

Tags: c#, wpf

Делаю программу WPF с использованием 3d-графики. Смысл программы - создать куб, вращающийся с помощью перетаскивания мыши.

Сама модель уже готова, обработчики событий также реализованы. Однако есть одна неприятность: при больших углах поворота у куба куда-то пропадают куски граней. Выглядит это примерно вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить?

Код формы на XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="laba10.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:laba10"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="RotateCube" Height="350" Width="525"
    MouseDown="Window_MouseDown" MouseMove="Window_MouseMove" MouseUp="Window_MouseUp">
<Grid>
    <Viewport3D>
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera Position="1.5,0,1" LookDirection="0,0,-2" FieldOfView="105" />
        </Viewport3D.Camera>
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <DirectionalLight x:Name="light" Color="#FFFFFF" Direction="-1,-1,-2" />
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            <ModelVisual3D.Transform>
                <RotateTransform3D>
                    <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        <AxisAngleRotation3D x:Name="rotatel" Axis="0 1 0"/>
                    </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                </RotateTransform3D>
            </ModelVisual3D.Transform>
        </ModelVisual3D>
        <!--wire model-->
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <GeometryModel3D>
                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                        <MeshGeometry3D 
                            Positions="-1 -1 0  1 -1 0  -1 1 0  1 1 0 -1 -1 2  1 -1 2 -1 1 2 1 1 2
                            -1 -0.99 0 1 -0.99 0 0.99 -1 0 0.99 1 0 -1 0.99 0 1 0.99 0 -0.99 1 0 -0.99 -1 0 
                            -1 -0.99 2 1 -0.99 2 0.99 -1 2 0.99 1 2 -1 0.99 2 1 0.99 2 -0.99 1 2 -0.99 -1 2"
                            TriangleIndices="0 1 8 1 9 8 10 1 11 1 3 11 2 12 13 13 3 2 0 15 2 15 14 2 0 4 8 
                            4 16 8 4 23 6 23 22 6 2 14 22 22 6 2 4 5 16 5 17 16 18 5 19 5 7 19 6 20 21 20 21 7 
                            9 1 17 17 1 5 11 3 19 19 3 7"/>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                        <DiffuseMaterial>
                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"  Opacity="1" />
                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>

                    <GeometryModel3D.Transform>
                        <TranslateTransform3D
        OffsetX="1.5" OffsetY="0." OffsetZ="-3"   >
                        </TranslateTransform3D>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Transform>
                </GeometryModel3D>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            <ModelVisual3D.Transform>
                <RotateTransform3D CenterX="1.5" CenterY="0." CenterZ="-3">
                    <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        <AxisAngleRotation3D x:Name="rotatew" Axis="0 1 0"/>
                    </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                </RotateTransform3D>
            </ModelVisual3D.Transform>
        </ModelVisual3D>
        <!--solid model-->
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <GeometryModel3D>
                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                        <MeshGeometry3D 
          Positions="-1 -1 0  1 -1 0  -1 1 0  1 1 0 -1 -1 2  1 -1 2 -1 1 2 1 1 2"
          Normals="0 0 1  0 0 1  0 0 1  0 0 1  0 0 1  0 0 1  0 0 1  0 0 1"
          TriangleIndices="0 1 2  1 3 2  0 4 2  4 6 2  1 5 3  
                            5 7 3  4 5 6  5 7 6  0 1 4  1 5 4  
                            2 3 6  3 6 7" />
                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                        <DiffuseMaterial>
                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Cyan" Opacity="0.5"/>
                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                    <!-- Translate the plane. -->
                    <GeometryModel3D.Transform>
                        <TranslateTransform3D
        OffsetX="1.5" OffsetY="0" OffsetZ="-3"   >
                        </TranslateTransform3D>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Transform>
                </GeometryModel3D>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            <ModelVisual3D.Transform>
                <RotateTransform3D
                        CenterX="1.5" CenterY="0." CenterZ="-3">
                    <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        <AxisAngleRotation3D x:Name="rotates" Axis="0 1 0"/>
                    </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                </RotateTransform3D>
            </ModelVisual3D.Transform>
        </ModelVisual3D>
    </Viewport3D>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Может быть, отъедьте подальше от куба? Наверное ваша камера получается при повороте внутри куба.

Comment: @VladD, попробовал по разным осям, куб двигается по форме, но это не помогает.

Comment: А если увести камеру _очень_ далеко? (Но без фанатизма, чтобы куб получился не очень маленький.)

Comment: @VladD Судя по всему, дело не в этом. [Не помогает](http://imgur.com/a/TBMYu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как часто это бывает, ответ лежал практически на поверхности. Проблема была в неправильно расставленных `TriangleIndices`. После того как я исправил их на значения, приводившиеся в руководствах, всё заработало как надо.

Правда, до сих пор не соображу, какие изменения нужно сделать для проволочной модели.